# how position a div ...px from another div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I was having problems with positioning my language option at the top of my blog. It was always on a different position on a Windows and a Mac. So I thought about making an inner and outer div. But I'm having troubles with the position of my inner div.

This is the result I want: [image: Image 1]
This is what I have now
[image: Image 2]

This is the code I have in my CSS on wordpress:

**EDITED**

```
.outer {
margin: auto;
overflow: visible;
background: white;
margin-left: 925px;
margin-top: -8px;
margin-bottom:-30px;
font-size: 11pt;
color: #E1BDC3;
border: 1px dotted #999999;
border-radius:8px;
width: 255px;
height: 48px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 10px;
z-index: 1000;
}

.inner {    
position: relative;
left: 160px;
top: -336px;
background: transparent; 
width: 150px;
z-index: 10001;   
}
```

The block with the border just has `<div class="outer"...`
And the inner div, the dropdown, is a widget that I'm trying to position at the top of the page, I gave the widget `"inner" class`.

QUESTION --> If I put `marging-right: 4px`, it starts counting from the right of the screen, how do I position (for example 4px) from the right of the **Outer div**?
So that it starts counting from the dotted border on the right (or the left, doesn't matter)

(I'm a beginner in HTML so if you know how to help me, could you please tell me what code I need, and where?

Comment: Can you include your html markup?

Comment: I can't give much HTML, because the dropdown menu, where it says "Nederlands" is a plugin. So no visible html. The only HTML that can be edited is ´<div class="outer">Choose language</div>´ ,this code is the ´<head>´ section

Comment: Right click and select 'inspect element' and that will show you the HTML markup for the plugin. Just copy/paste what you see there into your post.

Comment: I already tried that, it doesn't work, It's the plugin polylang. To go to an english version of the website. The HTML is hidden in the plugin, If I copy from inspect element, I copy the link that is available for the current page, it changes on every post and page of my blog

Comment: @Oihane Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use % to refer to positions on the screen. But your problem can be fix using `position: relative` to refer to the poition inside the parent object, and moving it with `top` and `left`

```css
.outer {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    background: white;
    margin-left: 925px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-bottom:-30px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: #E1BDC3;
    border: 1px dotted #999999;
    border-radius:8px;
    width: 255px;
    height: 48px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.inner {    
    position: relative;
    left: 159px;
    top: -17px;
    background: transparent; 
    width: 100px;     
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  OUTER
  <div class="inner"><select><option>INNER</option></select></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is that option select? because i can only give a name of a class to my plugin, I can only enter 1 value, --> CSS classes= ....

Comment: It's just an example to test how it will look like. You can put your plugin inside the `<div class="inner"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "how do I position (for example 4px) from the right of the Outer div?" you would do that by first determining how the elements relate to each other. This is determined by the `position` and `display` CSS properties. Depending on which `position` and `display` values your two elements have, the answer will vary.

The HTML markup you provide for your "outer" element shows that it is a `div`. Your CSS does not define a position for this element, so the browser default is `static`, i.e. `position:static`.

Your "inner" element is a mystery to us. If it is another `div` then it is another static position which we can help with. If it is a `ul` then it is an `inline` element, which will require a different answer.

Your markup is important here.

### EDIT

First thing, your 'outer' `div` is not actually containing your inner `div`. This is the outer div markup:

```
<div class="hide_on_mobile outer">Choose language</div>
```

You'll see it doesn't contain the element in question that we want to position. Therefore, like my first sentence states, we need to understand how our element in question relates to those around it.

In your situation, you are not in a good spot because the element you want to position is contained by elements that don't relate to your target element. Therefore the only way to position them in the same spot on all screen sizes is to position them `absolute`ly and use percentages.

Or the easy way, if you want to stick to one screen width:

```
.inner {
    position: relative;         //override by .widget_polylang element
    left: 27px;
    top: -17px;                 //override by .widget_polylang element
    background: transparent;
    width: 100px;               //override by .widget_polylang element
}
```

You'll see some of your key/value parameters are being outclassed by the   `.widget_polylang` element. The only way to change those is to edit the styles of `.widget_polylang` or add increased CSS specificity to `.inner`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying here, I'm not sure though about that inner element is. Would you mind giving me a code for what you're telling me? I understand what you are saying but i'm sure that I will fail at trying it myself. This is my blog --> www.oihanevalbuenaredondo.be . Maybe it shows in the 'inspect element' what kind of element the "inner" is

Comment: Hey, I can indeed edit the widget_polylang, I added it myself to the CSS and forgot about it I guess. I have changed the "inner" CSS as you said. It is hard though to know if it is finally okay on a mac computer now, I have a Windows so I can't check. I have edited my question, You can see the CSS I have now. I don't know if it works now though

Comment: Could you please help me any further for this language thing? I have edited to css as you said and deleted the polylang div class. It's still not showing up right on a Mac. I think the only way to get the 2 things even is to position the inner css element, starting from the border of the outer css element, if that is possible

Comment: @Oihane Can you edit your outer div to be inside your container div? Like so: `<div class="container">  <div class="outer"> Choose Language </div> *the rest of the container code* </div>`